# How to rehash password which is stored in database using MD5?

Tags: java, encryption

I have used MD5 for password encryption and stored encrypted format password in database. Now I want to rehash it. How can I do this?

Comment: why would anyone want to re-hash anything?

Comment: @kovags because when user try to enter using password n username.it must match with stored one as stored is hashed value and user entering original value......please tell me the solution

Comment: Saying "Give me" and "Tell me" is rude. Please ask questions the smart way :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to change/upgrade the hashing algorithm used in your database.

Technically it's not possible to do that, if you only have the hash result of the old system.

**But** you can create a new hash value each time a user successfully logs in using his password: in this case you first use the normal procedure to check for correctness (hash the input, compare that with the stored hash) and if that's correct, hash the entered password with the new system (preferably with a good salt and using a good hashing algorithm, it's probably best to use [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)) and store that as the new hash.

Comment: yes i have done that only.....thanks...but when user forget the password then at that time how to recover it????

Comment: @Smith: you can't! That's the idea of hashing it in the first place! You can't send your users their password, you can only generate a new one and let them use that from now on. Sending out passwords is a huge security risk anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You dont re-hash the password.

You take the password entered from the logon screen and hash it the same way the stored password was hashed and then compare the two hashed values. If they match the passwords are the same.

Comment: Rule 1 of security, DONT store passwords. If the user forgets, then there are various methods to recreate one.

Comment: @adrin if we dont wanna store password then how to achieve it????how to compare it..

Comment: When you create the account - you take the users password, hash it, and store the hash. When the user wants to login they enter their password, you hash what the user entered and compare that hash against the stored hash, if they are the same then the password is the same.

Comment: yes right but to compare its hash and stored hash i must stored his entered password hash.......rght ??

Comment: no, just have the app pull the stored hash into memory and compare in code....If at any time you transmit the unhashed password over any network you have a security flaw....

Comment: @Adrin please i dont know app pull n all,can you please tell me how to achieve it??

Comment: To be fair to you and me, I think that is better asked as separate question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.  Hashing is one-way, you can't get the original password from a hash and then rehash it.